# How to get random post from reddit

Tags: javascript, api, reddit

I want to get random post from https://www.reddit.com/r/creepy/

When I request https://www.reddit.com/r/creepy.json I can get the first 27 posts from the subreddit. In the json response there is this thing "after=t3_dc9whe" - I can pass it to the next request and get next page.

What I want to do is to get random "after"

Is there any way to get this done?
Maybe there is a pattern and I can randomize letters and numbers in this "after"?

This is a link to my repo app: https://github.com/Krystian93/CreepyJson

The app is working but shows only first 27 post from first page of the subreddit.

Comment: I don't know the Reddit API, though the usage of `"dist": 27` and `"after":"t3_dc9whe"` show me that their API is using cursor based paging. The `after` appears to relate to the Id of a child post - see related `"name"` values. Ultimately its not possible to randomize cursor based paging unless you know the names/id's of all posts.

Answer (score 3):

There's an API endpoint to get a random post:

`GET [/r/subreddit]/random`

https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_random